# Track delimiter change in Ruby regex

Tags: regex, ruby

I've got a string in the following form:

```
hello - world - hi / usa - uk
```

This is an example input from my app which may also come in variations such as:

```
hello / world / hi - usa / uk
```

The possible delimiters would be `/`, `|` and `-`.

The key difference for me **is the delimiter switch** half way through the string. That would  signify a new pair or strings. I'm not sure how to track that.

Effectively I'd love an output of the following form:

For the first example:

```
['hello - world - hi', 'usa - uk']
```

For the second:

```
['hello / world / hi', 'usa / uk']
```

Comment: If the string were `"hello / world / hi - usa | uk"` what would be the desired return value?

Comment: `['hello / world / hi', 'usa | uk']`. The idea would be that `-` is the first delimiter change...

Comment: You may wish to edit your question to include the above example. My understanding is that you wish to split the string on the first of the three delimiters in the string that differs from the first of the three delimiters in the string or, equivalently, if `d` is the first of the three delimiters that appears in the string you wish to split the string on the first of the three delimiters following `d` that differs from `d`.  If correct, you may wish to include something along those lines in the statement of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Define the Problem

Regular expressions should not be used as blunt instruments. Let your actual code do some of the work. By reframing your problem as:

> Given that I have lines containing multi-valued delimiters
> When I scan the line
> Then I should split the line on the third delimiter.

you may end up with a more tractable problem statement that better articulates what you want and why. Doing this also suggests a natural implementation using [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-split).

If the problem statement above doesn't accurately describe *what* you want (regardless of *how* you plan to implement it), then you may either need to be clearer about your objectives, or perform some sort of normalization of your data so that it's easier to work with.

### A Worked Solution in Ruby 2.7.1

Your core issue is that you need a way to define both the most likely field separator and *internal* record separator for each line at runtime. For this solution, we'll do that by counting the number of times the characters listed in *DELIMITERS* appear on each line.

```rb
DELIMITERS = "-/|"

data = [
  "hello - world - hi / usa - uk",
  "hello / world / hi - usa / uk",
]

# Find the field and record separators for a given string, e.g. the
# most- and least-used delimiters on the line.
def find_separators str
  delimiter_count = Hash.new 0
  regexp = /[#{DELIMITERS}]/

  str.scan(regexp).each { delimiter_count[_1] += 1 }
  delimiter_candidates = delimiter_count.sort_by { |k,v| v }.reverse

  # The field delimiter should be the most common separator, and will be
  # first in the sorted array. The internal record separator will be the
  # least-used separator on the line, and should be last in the array.
  #
  # WARN: Tie-breaking on pathological data is up to you.
  field_sep, record_sep =
    delimiter_candidates.first[0], delimiter_candidates.last[0]

  [field_sep, record_sep]
end

data.map do |line|
  field_sep, record_sep = find_separators line
  line.split(record_sep).map &:strip
end

#=> [["hello - world - hi", "usa - uk"], ["hello / world / hi", "usa / uk"]]
```

#### Considerations

While there are simpler approaches, this one should work with an arbitrary number of delimiters provided that:

1. You don't use delimiters (other than the internal record separator) that are likely to be found within fields in your data set.
2. The field separator is always the most common separator character on each line.
3. There is only one internal record separator on each line.
4. You don't have fields/records littered with stray delimiters.

All of these problems can be worked around, but any delimited data set is going to have problems if it's not well-formed. This solution does what's expected given the inputs and outputs from your original question, but if your data is inconsistent then your mileage will almost certainly vary.

Comment: Great answer! It really helped me out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will present two solutions. The first, which is the one I would advocate in practice, uses Ruby methods and two very simple regular expressions; the second employs a complex regular expression that is the argument of [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-split).

I've included the latter solution because I believe it has educational value for readers who wish to improve their understanding of the use of regular expressions. The expression includes, for example, the tokens `\G` and `\K`, which may be unfamiliar to some readers.

**Conventional solution**

```
def split_on_second(str)
  delimiters = '-/|'
  i1 = str.index(/[#{delimiters}]/)
  return [str] if i1.nil?
  i2 = str.index(/[#{delimiters.delete(str[i1])}]/)
  i2.nil? ? [str] : str.split(/ *#{str[i2]} */, 2)
end
   
split_on_second "hello - world - hi / usa - uk"
   #=> ["hello - world - hi", "usa - uk"] 
split_on_second "hello / world / hi - usa / uk"
  #=> ["hello / world / hi", "usa / uk"] 
split_on_second "hello / world / hi - usa | uk"
  #=> ["hello / world / hi", "usa | uk"] 
split_on_second "hello / world / hi - usa - uk"
  #=> ["hello / world / hi", "usa - uk"]
```

Here I simply use [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-index) to find the index of the first delimiter `d` among the three possibilities then use the same method again to find the index of the first delimiter among the two delimiters other than `d`.

Note the use of the second argument in `String#split` (`2`). Without it the last example above would return:

```
  ["hello / world / hi", "usa", "uk"]
```

The calculations could be sped up slightly by replacing the line `i2 = ...` with

```
i2 = str.index(/[#{delimiters.delete(str[i1])}]/, i1+1)
```

which begins the search at string offset `i1+1`.

**Use a single regular expression**

One could match the following regular expression, splitting the string on the content of capture group 2, and then stripping extra spaces from each string in the returned array.

```
r = /^(?:^|(?!^)\G)(?=[^-\/|\n]*([-\/|])(?:[^-\/|\n]*\1)*[^-\/|\n]*(?!\1)([-\/|]))(?:(?!\2).)*\K\2/
```

```
str = "hello - world - hi / usa - uk"
str =~ r
a = str.split($2)
  #=> ["hello / world / hi ", " usa | uk"] 
a.map(&:strip)
  #=> ["hello / world / hi", "usa | uk"]
```

```
str = "hello / world / hi - usa / uk"
str =~ r
str.split($2).map(&:strip)
  #=> ["hello / world / hi", "usa / uk"]
```

```
str = "hello / world / hi - usa | uk"
str =~ r
str.split($2, 2).map(&:strip)
  #=> ["hello / world / hi", "usa | uk"]
```

[Start your engine!](https://rubular.com/r/Z8dlcq7mwhpNqJ)

See also [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QCOyAI/4/) for details about the tokens the comprise the regex. (Move your cursor across the regex.)

Ruby's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                 : match start of line
(?:               : begin non-capture group
  ^               : march beginning of line
  |               : or
  (?!^)           : negative lookahead asserts current position is
                    not the beginning of a line
  \G              : asserts position at the end of the previous match
                    or the start of the string for the first match
)                 : end non-capture group
(?=               : begin positive lookahead
  [^-\/|\n]*      : match 0+ chars other than those listed
  ([-\/|])        : match '-', '/' or '|' and save to capture group 1
  (?:             : begin non-capture group
    [^-\/|\n]*    : match 0+ chars other than those listed
    \1            : match the content of capture group 1
  )*              : end non-capture group and execute 0+ times
  [^-\/|\n]*      : match 0+ chars other than those listed
  (?!\1)          : negative lookahead asserts next char is not
                    the content of capture group 1 
  ([-\/|])        : match one of the characters listed and save to
                    capture group 2
)                 : end positive lookahead
(?:               : begin non-capture group
  (?!\2)          : negative lookahead asserts next char does not
                  : equal the content of capture group 2
  .               : match any char
)*                : end non-capture group and execute 0+ times
\K                : reset the starting point of the reported match
                    and exclude any previously-consumed characters
                    from the reported match
\2                : match the content of capture group 2
```

Comment: GREAT answer! Probably what I was looking for in the first place! Won't change my accepted answer since @Todd was the first the understand what I was trying to achieve and broke down the problem for me but anyone looking for a "one-liner" should definitely have a look at yours.